# Sabre PAX Details error ".SNGL ITEM FIELD.NOT ENT BGNG WITH"

Tags: xml, web-services, soap, sabre

Sometimes I am getting error like

> `.SNGL` item `field.not ent BGNG` with

But most of the time I getting success result. I am not sure where I am doing wrong. Here is my PAX Payload.

```
<AddRemarkRQ>
  <RemarkInfo>
    <FOP_Remark Type="CHECK" />
    <Remark Code="H" SegmentNumber="A" Type="General">
      <Text>GDS FARE 23156.00/Tax 1990.00</Text>
    </Remark>
  </RemarkInfo>
</AddRemarkRQ>
<TravelItineraryAddInfoRQ>
  <AgencyInfo>
    <Address>
      <AddressLine>Go Hi Fly</AddressLine>
      <CityName>Kuala Lumpur</CityName>
      <CountryCode>MY</CountryCode>
      <PostalCode>55100</PostalCode>
      <StreetNmbr>NO 3</StreetNmbr>
      <VendorPrefs>
         <Airline Hosted="false" />
      </VendorPrefs>
    </Address>
    <Ticketing PseudoCityCode="PCC" QueueNumber="56" TicketType="7TAW" TicketTimeLimit="08-22T01:00" ShortText="Test text" />
  </AgencyInfo>
  <CustomerInfo>
    <ContactNumbers>
      <ContactNumber NameNumber="1.1" Phone="1875950000" PhoneUseType="H" />
    </ContactNumbers>
    <Email Address="sayem@asteriskbd.com" NameNumber="1.1" Type="TO" ShortText="Online Booking" />
    <PersonName NameNumber="1.1" PassengerType="ADT">
      <GivenName>AbuMR</GivenName>
      <Surname>Sayem</Surname>
    </PersonName>
  </CustomerInfo>
</AddRemarkRQ>
```

Comment: I am unable to reproduce your error.
Wondering why the </AddRemarkRQ> at the end of your sample instead of </TravelItineraryAddInfoRQ>.

Normally the error you are getting is due to a data formatted in a way that is not accepted for a given field, but using your same values I don't get the error.

Also, when you say PAX Payload, do you mean you are using the PassengerDetailsRQ service? If you post the whole request it will help I think.

Comment: Hi @fcarreno, Yes I am using PassengerDetailsRQ Service. Here is my full pax request link [http://tripswego.com/pax_req.xml](http://tripswego.com/pax_req.xml)

Comment: thanks for the request. I'm not getting any error. I had to change the ticket time limit date as it was past, but other than that, I did not change anything. I am doubting about the child passenger names including an asterisk (e.g.: AliMSTR*C06) - but anyway that worked for me without any problems. Are you sure that's the exact request that was failing?
What airline are you trying to book?

Comment: I had solved this adding extra `contactNumbers` of type Agency(A) before the contact type Home(H).

Answer (score 2):

I think you called the same service twice without doing an ignore transaction in between, and the agency address information can be added just once.

So, the first works and the 2nd time fails with that error.

Comment: No, I am calling `PassengerDetailsRQ` only one time.

Comment: .SNGL item field.not ent BGNG with means that you cannot add the same information twice. That is why it says that it is a single element field. Of the elements you have in that request, only the agency address can only be used once. So, I still believe you called the PassengerDetails twice using the same BinarySecurytyToken without an IgnoreTransaction in between. May be you called the TravelItineraryAddInfo, but in the end the situation is the same, the address cannot be added twice.